# File Upload Validation In Codeigniter

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am trying to validate file upload for image uploading, but it is not getting the validation like other fields. I am using `Form_Validation.php` process for validation.

Image uploading array:

```
array(
            'field'=>'image',
            'label' => 'Image',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
```

when i try to upload the image it did not response like it is required etc. I also want to validate it for `.jpg` etc and "how to set the file value on incorrect file like instead of `.jpg` we try to upload the `.pdf`" like we set the value of input field `set_value('field name')` etc.

I checked a lot of questions and also try to use call method, but did not able to fix it.

***UPDATE:***

Please provide detail answer with code example. Please use the form_validation.php way in example and also provide the callback example code, so i can read / learn and modify it accordingly.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
 public function Task()
    {
        if ($this->form_validation->run('Sub_Admin/task') == FALSE) {
            $this->data['Task'] = $this->bm->get_usr();
            $data['title'] = "Add New Task";
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/nav');
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/task', $this->data);
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/footer');
        }
        else
        {

            $config['upload_path'] = './taskimages/'; //The path where the image will be save
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; //Images extensions accepted
            $config['max_size'] ='10048'; //The max size of the image in kb's
            //$config['max_width']  = '1024'; //The max of the images width in px
            //$config['max_height']  = '768'; //The max of the images height in px
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE; //If exists an image with the same name it will overwrite. Set to false if don't want to overwrite
            $this->load->library('upload', $config); //Load the upload CI library
            $this->load->initialize($config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('task');
            $file_info = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $file_info['file_name'];
            $data = array(
                'Job_Title' => $this->input->post('jtitle'),
                'Priority' => $this->input->post('jnature'),
                'Assignee' => $this->input->post('assigne'),
                'Employee_Name' => $this->input->post('assignto'),
                'Due_Date' => $this->input->post('ddate'),
                'Reminder' => $this->input->post('reminder'),
                'Task_Image' => $file_name,
            );

            $this->bm->add_task($data);

        }
    }
```

*I am already using CI uploading class but it is not working, and now i want to validate the image/ file from form_validation side.*

Comment: SO is not a coding service (not even for bounty). Provide what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: @msz I have updated my code according your question.

Comment: I think following answer will help you.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143626/codeigniter-3-how-to-get-image-file-in-callback-validation-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a complete example for your problem, I hope it will help. In the following code I am using CI's Form validation callback and Form Validation Custom Error Messages.

**Controller:** Front.php

class Front extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('form');
}

public function upload_image() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    if ($this->form_validation->run('user_data') == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('form');
    }
    else {
        echo 'You form Submitted Successfully ';
    }
}

public function validate_image() {
    $check = TRUE;
    if ((!isset($_FILES['my_image'])) || $_FILES['my_image']['size'] == 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'The {field} field is required');
        $check = FALSE;
    }
    else if (isset($_FILES['my_image']) && $_FILES['my_image']['size'] != 0) {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "GIF", "PNG");
        $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["my_image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['my_image']['tmp_name']);
        $type = $_FILES['my_image']['type'];
        if (!in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'Invalid Image Content!');
            $check = FALSE;
        }
        if(filesize($_FILES['my_image']['tmp_name']) > 2000000) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'The Image file size shoud not exceed 20MB!');
            $check = FALSE;
        }
        if(!in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', "Invalid file extension {$extension}");
            $check = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return $check;
}
```

}

**View:** form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="<?= base_url() ?>">Form</a></h1>
    <?php if(!empty(validation_errors())): ?>
        <p><?= validation_errors() ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= form_open('front/upload_image', ['enctype' => "multipart/form-data"]) ?>
    <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" value="<?= set_value('name') ?>"></label>
    <label>E-mail: </label><input type="email" name="email" value="<?= set_value('email') ?>"></label>
    <input type="file" name="my_image">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <?= form_close() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
        'user_data' => array(
                array(
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'label' => 'Name',
                        'rules' => 'trim|required'
                ),
                array(
                        'field' => 'email',
                        'label' => 'Email',
                        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email'
                ),
                array(
                        'field' => 'my_image',
                        'label' => 'Image',
                        'rules' => 'callback_validate_image'
                )
        )
);
```

In above example first I am validating the `name` and `email` and for the Image I am calling the `validate_image` function to validate it, since form_validation library does not provide image validation but i has callbacks to do custom validations, the `validate_image` will check image content type then check image file size and then check image extension if any of these requirements are not fulfilled it will set error message for each requirement using `set_message()` function of `form_validation` library.

Comment: can you please also tell me that "how to set the previous value of the image" like we set for other textboxes etc `<?php echo set_value('task')?>` i try this but when i submit the form it show the error but value is not resetting for it.

Comment: @msz due to security reasons the value of a filebox cannot be set, if it was allowed then any site can steal files from your file system. So browsers will not allow it to set the value without user interaction. You can use Ajax form upload which will keep all your data until your server respond the data is okay and you can redirect the user to a success page or reset the form.

Answer (score 3):

How about [File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html) from CI?

Validations are also available from the class:

```
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;
```

The link includes the Upload form, Success page and the Controller.

Just follow the instructions from there and you'll never get lost.

Comment: please check **UPDATE 2**

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are not getting error because you set validation rules, you also initialized configuration but after uploading class you are not checking that either file is being uploaded or errors.

Please check below mentioned solution, it will help you fix this.

**Update 1 :**

In order to call a specific group, you will pass its name to the `$this->form_validation->run('task')` method. I can not see any `$config['task']` array in your code. Please check my below mentioned code and update based on your `inputs`.

```
public function Task() {

    $config = array(
        'task' => array(
            array(
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required'
            )
    ));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    if ($this->form_validation->run('task') == FALSE) {
        $this->data['Task'] = $this->bm->get_usr();
        $data['title'] = "Add New Task";
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/nav');
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/task', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/footer');
    } else {
        $fconfig['upload_path'] = './taskimages/';
        $fconfig['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $fconfig['max_size'] = '10048';
        $fconfig['overwrite'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $fconfig); //Load the upload CI library
        $this->load->initialize($fconfig);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('my_image')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('form' ,$error);
        } else {
            $file_info = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $file_info['my_image'];
            $data = array(
                'Job_Title' => $this->input->post('jtitle'),
                'Priority' => $this->input->post('jnature'),
                'Assignee' => $this->input->post('assigne'),
                'Employee_Name' => $this->input->post('assignto'),
                'Due_Date' => $this->input->post('ddate'),
                'Reminder' => $this->input->post('reminder'),
                'Task_Image' => $file_name,
            );

            $this->bm->add_task($data);

            $data['upload_data'] = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('YOUR_SUCCESS_VIEW PAGE', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: not working.... no error is showing if i select .pdf and also it is not resetting the file value / name.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this code for multiple images upload.
Now try below code, Hope it will help.

```
 public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png|bmp';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('session');

    }



 public function Task() {
        if ($this->form_validation->run('Sub_Admin/task') == FALSE) {
            $this->data['Task'] = $this->bm->get_usr();
            $data['title'] = "Add New Task";
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/nav');
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/task', $this->data);
            $this->load->view('Subadmin/footer');
        } else {

            $filesCount = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            $result     = '';
            if($filesCount > 0) {
                $event_id     = trim($this->input->post('event_name'));
                for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {

                    $_FILES['gallery']['name']      = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gallery']['type']      = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name']  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gallery']['error']     = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['gallery']['size']      = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

                    $image = $_FILES['gallery']['name'];
                    $directoryPath = date('Y/M/');

                    $path_info = pathinfo($image);
                    //check file type valid or not
                    if(in_array($path_info['extension'], array('jpg', 'jpeg','png', 'gif','JPG','JPEG'))){
                        // Upload job picture
                        $random = time();
                        $config['upload_path']   = './taskimages/';
                        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
                        $config['file_name']     = $random;
                        $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
                        $config['max_size']      = '250000000';
                        $config['max_width']     = '75000000';
                        $config['max_height']    = '7500000';

                        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                        $this->upload->initialize($config);

                        ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
                        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

                        if ($this->upload->do_upload('gallery')) {

                            $imageArray = $this->upload->data();
                            $image_name = $imageArray['raw_name'] . '' . $imageArray['file_ext']; // Job Attachment

                            $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                            $config1['source_image'] = './taskimages/' . $image_name;
                            $config1['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                            $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                            $config1['width'] = 620;
                            $config1['height'] = 540;

                            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                            $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
                            $this->image_lib->resize();
                            $this->image_lib->clear();


                            $file_name = $image_name_thumb = $imageArray['raw_name'] . '_thumb' . $imageArray['file_ext'];
                            $data = array(
                                'Job_Title' => $this->input->post('jtitle'),
                                'Priority' => $this->input->post('jnature'),
                                'Assignee' => $this->input->post('assigne'),
                                'Employee_Name' => $this->input->post('assignto'),
                                'Due_Date' => $this->input->post('ddate'),
                                'Reminder' => $this->input->post('reminder'),
                                'Task_Image' => $file_name,
                            );

                            $this->bm->add_task($data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I write only sample files upload. Change it according to your requirement.
**controller/Files.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Files extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function upload(){
    $data = array();

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('file');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('task', '', 'callback_file_check');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
        //upload configuration
        $config['upload_path']   = 'uploads/files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
        $config['max_size']      = 1024;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        //upload file to directory
        if($this->upload->do_upload('task')){
            //YOU CAN DO WHAT DO THE PROCESS
        }else{
            $data['error_msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }        
    //load the view
    $this->load->view('upload_view', $data);
}

public function file_check($str){
    $allowed_mime_type_arr = array('application/pdf','image/gif','image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/x-png'); //HERE you CAN GIVE VALID FILE EXTENSION
    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($_FILES['task']['name']);
    if(isset($_FILES['task']['name']) && $_FILES['task']['name']!=""){
        if(in_array($mime, $allowed_mime_type_arr)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('file_check', 'Please select only pdf/gif/jpg/png file.');
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('file_check', 'Please choose a file to upload.');
        return false;
    }
}
}
?>
```

**view/upload_view.php**

```
<?php 
if(!empty($success_msg)){
    echo '<p class="statusMsg">'.$success_msg.'</p>';
}elseif(!empty($error_msg)){
    echo '<p class="statusMsg">'.$error_msg.'</p>';
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>files/upload">
   <p><input type="task" name="task"/></p>
   <?php echo form_error('task','<p class="help-block">','</p>'); ?>
   <p><input type="submit" name="uploadFile" value="UPLOAD"/></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public function add_partner()
{ 
     $config =[
    'upload_path'    =>   './uploads_image',
    'allowed_types'  =>   'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',//Image allowed Type
              ]; 
     $this->load->library('upload',$config);//load image liabrary
     $post=$this->input->post();
     if($this->form_validation->run('partner') && $this->upload-
     >do_upload('userfile'))
     {    
       $data = $this->upload->data();
       $image_path = ("uploads_image/" .$data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext']);
       $post['partner_image'] = $image_path; //partner_image tabelfield name

       unset($post['submit']);
       $this->partner_model->add_partner($post);//data to model
     }
     else
     {       
       $upload_error= $this->upload->display_errors();        
       $this->load->view('admin/add_partner',['upload_error'=>$upload_error]);
     } 
}
In view 
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="image" class="col-lg-5 control-label"> Upload Image<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-lg-7"> <?php echo form_upload(['name'=>'userfile','class'=>'form-control','data-max-size'=>' 2048','value'=>set_value('userfile')]); ?> </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4"> <?php if(isset($upload_error)) echo $upload_error; ?> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In CODEIGNITER 4 the Validation class includes features of file validation. you can achieve it by the following block of code.

in Config/Validation.php add

```
public $signup = [
        'username' => [
            'rules'  => 'required|alpha',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'You must choose a Username.'
            ]
        ],
        'profile_image' => [
            'rules' => 'uploaded[profile_image]|max_size[profile_image,1024]|ext_in[profile_image,png,jpg]|max_dims[profile_image,1000,1000]',
            'label' => 'profile image'
        ]
    ];
```

in your controller add following code

```
public function register()
{
    $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
        //$validation->setRuleGroup('signup');
        if (!$this->validate('signup')) {
            //$validationErrors = $validation->getErrors();
            echo view('register', [
                'validation' => $validation
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            // your logic goes here....
            echo view('Success');
        }
    } else {
        echo view('register', [
            'validation' => $validation
        ]);
    }
}
```

your view will be like

```
    <?= $validation->listErrors() ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <label>Full Name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" size="50" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <label>Profile Picture</label><br/>
        <input type="file" name="profile_image" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('profile_image') ?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4"><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting error using CI uploading class because you are not calling error meothod of it. Change your update 2 code as below

```
public function Task()
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run('Sub_Admin/task') == FALSE) {
        $this->data['Task'] = $this->bm->get_usr();
        $data['title'] = "Add New Task";
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/nav');
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/task', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('Subadmin/footer');
    }
    else
    {

        $config['upload_path'] = './taskimages/'; //The path where the image will be save
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; //Images extensions accepted
        $config['max_size'] ='10048'; //The max size of the image in kb's
        //$config['max_width']  = '1024'; //The max of the images width in px
        //$config['max_height']  = '768'; //The max of the images height in px
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE; //If exists an image with the same name it will overwrite. Set to false if don't want to overwrite
        $this->load->library('upload', $config); //Load the upload CI library
        $this->load->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('task'))
        {       
                $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors(); //Here you will get errors. You can handle with your own way
                echo $upload_error; //<------------you can echo it for debugging purpose
                $data['error'] = $upload_error; //<-------------you can send it in view to display error in view.
                $this->load->view('your_view' ,$data); //<---pass data to view
        }
        else
        {
            $file_info = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $file_info['file_name'];
            $data = array(
                'Job_Title' => $this->input->post('jtitle'),
                'Priority' => $this->input->post('jnature'),
                'Assignee' => $this->input->post('assigne'),
                'Employee_Name' => $this->input->post('assignto'),
                'Due_Date' => $this->input->post('ddate'),
                'Reminder' => $this->input->post('reminder'),
                'Task_Image' => $file_name,
            );

            $this->bm->add_task($data);
        }



    }
}
```

**In view**

```
echo (isset($error))?$error:"";
```

Comment: not working.... no error is showing if i select .pdf and also it is not resetting the file value / name.